# A Reboot() command with failover

Tags: linux, embedded, shutdown, reboot

I'm implementing a Reboot() call in my application. It's an embedded application, so no console, keyboard or power switch. The Reboot() must eventually restart the system no matter what. Ideally, I want it to fail gracefully.

I've had systems in the past cause problems where a call to `reboot` or `shutdown` did not result in a reboot of the machine. e.g. failure to sync drives, unmount a removed USB flash drive.

My system is embedded, with a read-only mounted root filing system, so a sudden power off isn't a big issue. But I do write logs to a Flash disc and I'd like to preserve this as much as possible.

My current Reboot() looks like this:

```
void Reboot()
{
    system( "reboot" );     // try the reboot
    sleep(2);
    system( "reboot -f" );      // force
    sleep(2);
    system( "reboot -f -n" );   // force and don't try to sync
    sleep(2);
    system( "kill 1" );     // process 1 is the root process of all
    sleep(2);
    Reset();
}
```

The reset command is a hard system reset that will not fail. The system also has a Watchdog timer.

Would people care to comment on anything to add/replace/change in my Reboot() function?

e.g. should I use [Magic SysRq](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/rebooting-magic-way)?

Comment: what about init 6 ?

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified that I'm running Busybox. No run levels. But changing the run level, and calling the kill scripts just calls reboot command in the end anyway.

Answer (score 0):

> The system also has a Watchdog timer.

I think this is your answer - flush the block cache and stop kicking the watchdog. I've worked on many embedded systems, and can't recall one that performed a reboot using the traditional server/PC mechanisms.

Comment: I'm pretty sure my Reset() function uses the Watchdog to reboot the system.  The point of the question was to see if I could do anything better before I forced the reboot (via the watchdog).